# Replacing HTML with angular-ized HTML via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In a scenario where I'm not able to directly control the HTML (it's created by a user), is it proper 'angular etiquette' to iterate through the DOM via javascript and add angular statements/directives before bootstrapping angular manually?

When you can't control the HTML file, is there a way to add angular into the HTML via angular? Or at least in a more angular-friendly way?

Answer (score 1):

Before the HTML is compiled by angular (the angular compile phase), there is nothing wrong with modifying it. However, once the compile phase has started (i.e. the directive's compile function is being called), you should only modify its children.

To answer your second question - yes, there is a way to bootstrap your HTML via angular without having to add any angular-specific attributes (such as ng-app).  This can be done as follows:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: What about adding other ng-attributes before the compile function? Like `ng-click` or `ng-show` etc...

Comment: The above recommendation applies to directives including ng-attributes.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. What about adding other ng-attributes with angular before the compile function? It just feels really hacky to have a block of jquery that runs at the top and then all my angular below. It seems like there should be some way of adding attributes or changing attributes via angular.